# Adding pagination on template page wordpress

Tags: pagination, page-template

in the template page loop get posts from tag which name is raspee, post per page are 5. pagination show in the page but not working..

**What is problem in my code??**

> Template-page

```
<?php /* Template Name: Raspee */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$args=array('posts_per_page'=>5 , 'tag' => raspee );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( have_posts() ) :
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    get_template_part('content');

endwhile;

next_posts_link();
previous_posts_link(); 

endif;
$wp_query = null;
$wp_query = $original_query;    
wp_reset_postdata();    
?>  

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not add "paged" in WP_Query args array ,that's why your pagination not working. try this code , it will work definitely

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$args=array('posts_per_page'=>5, 'tag' => 'raspee', 'paged'=>$paged);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: '$args=array('posts_per_page'=>5 , 'tag' => 'raspee' ,paged'=>$paged);' editing  this line thats way now its work fine...